# Monomial decomposition as product of smaller monomials

Tags: combinatorics

Is there an algorithm to get all possible decompositions of a monomial as the product of smaller monomials ?

For example $x^2 y^3$ is $x * xy^3$, $x^2 * y^3$, $xy * xy^2$, and so on.

For a monomial in one inderminate, I know I can use the integer partitions of the monomial degree.

But this does not apply when there are at least two indeterminates.

(Sorry for misuse of vocabulary and may be uncomplete tags : I am french).

Note : this is a step in construction of an invariant polynomial as described in DOI : 10.1016/j.ijsolstr.2005.05.021.